# Accessing elements in C# dictionary

Tags: c#, c++, dictionary, iterator

I am a newbie currently translating C++ code to C#. I have a map

```
map<string, Object*> table;
```

and a function

```
void define(const string& symbol, Object* definition)
{
    map<string, Object*>::iterator iter = table.find(symbol);//returns iterator to element with key "symbol," else sets equal to map::end
    if (iter != table.end())//if key is in map
    {
        delete (*iter).second;
        table.erase(iter);
    }
    table.insert(pair<string, Object*>(symbol,definition->clone()));
}
```

and I want to create the equivalent function in C#. I've created a Dictionary:

```
private Dictionary<string, Object> table = new Dictionary<string, Object>();
```

and here is my function so far

```
public void define(string symbol, Object definition)
    {
        if (table.ContainsKey(symbol))
        {
//function body
        }
```

and now need my function body to accomplish the same thing. From my research, it doesn't seem like C# has the same iterator structure.

Comment: Careful. Many things in C++ and C# look similar, but handle completely differently. Notably, make sure you understand the differences between the handling of values, pointers and references in both C++ and C#; in this code snippet, I can see you're `delete`ing the value that was there before, and replacing it with a clone of the value passed as an argument. Make sure you understand the reasons behind this - xanatos' answer might very well be perfectly fine in C#, but it might also be entirely wrong. And of course, do you *really* want to use `object`? That's a bit suspicious.

Comment: Note that the C++ is only that complicated because it foolishly tries to manage memory using raw pointers. With a more sensible mapped type (`Object`, or possibly `unique_ptr<Object>`) it would simply be `table[symbol] = definition` (possibly with a `move`). I imagine the equivalent C# would be similar to that.

Answer (score 3):

Your method in the end replaces an element (if present), or adds it... In C# you can simply:

```
public void define(string symbol, Object definition)
{
    table[symbol] = definition;
}
```

Note that if `definition` can be `IDisposable` and you have ownership of it, then it would be better to `Dispose()` it, in a similar manner to the one used in C++

```
public void define(string symbol, Object definition)
{
    object oldDefinition;

    if (table.TryGetValue(symbol, out oldDefinition) && oldDefinition != null) 
    {
        IDisposable disp = oldDefinition as IDisposable;

        if (disp != null)
        {
            disp.Dispose();
        }
    }

    table[symbol] = definition;
}
```

**For the clone()**

You have to choose how to handle the `clone()`. Being references even in C++, it is a little strange that they chosed to `clone()` the `Object`. If you want to `clone()` it, clearly you'll need to expose a method for your `CloneableObject` to clone it. Note that `Object` (or `object`) in C# isn't cloneable "out of the box". You have to write the code to clone it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need an iterator over dictionary in `c#`. You can use one of the following way to iterate over `dictionary` in `c#`

```
foreach(var pair in table)
{
    var key = pair.Key;
    var value = pair.Value;
}
```

or

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, Object> entry in table)
{
    // do something with entry.Value or entry.Key
}
```

or

```
for (int index = 0; index < table.Count; index++) {
  var item = table.ElementAt(index);
  var itemKey = item.Key;
  var itemValue = item.Value;
}
```

You can add `if` clause in `foreach` loop and process it.